# Ubuntu boot screen lock on vmware player

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware-player

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 on VmWare-Player 10. My host system is Windows 7. It worked fine, but since I restarted my host system (I have done this often and it was working without any problems) it stucks at the ubuntu boot up:

[image]

I have restarted my host system and it locked again:

[image]

Do I have to change something in the log files or how can I fix this?

Thanks in advance,
clax

Comment: I switched the current kernel version in the grub menu to 3.16.0-60 and now it works fine again. But I dont know how to handle the current kernel version, maybe ubuntu is already fixing the problem.